# Aiohttp connection testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, aiohttp

I have to write some examples of unit test(s) for the following function:

```py
async def logs(cont, name):
    conn = aiohttp.UnixConnector(path="/var/run/docker.sock")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
        async with session.get(f"http://xx/containers/{cont}/logs?follow=1&stdout=1") as resp:
            async for line in resp.content:
                print(name, line)
```

But I even don't know where to start since I've never tested async connections. Please, give me some guidence or hits.

I've tried to ask ChatGPT (shame on me) but its anwsers were rubbish.